# How can I get more detailed filesystem information on FUSE filesystems?

Tags: linux, fuse

On Linux systems, it is possible to identify "regular" filesystems
using `statfs(2)` and inspecting the `f_type`. Constants for several
filesystem types are mentioned in the `statfs(2)` manpage, such as

```
EXT4_SUPER_MAGIC      0xEF53
BTRFS_SUPER_MAGIC     0x9123683E
FUSE_SUPER_MAGIC      0x65735546
PROC_SUPER_MAGIC      0x9fa0
SYSFS_MAGIC           0x62656572
```

(It turns out that those are actually defined in `linux/magic.h`.)

I would like to be able to distinguish well-known remote filesystems
(such as sshfs) from well-known local filesystems (such as the
ntfs-3g). Is there any way to find out more about FUSE-based
filesystems, such as a name at this point?

Answer (score 1):

As per [some old IBM fuse documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-fuse/) and the implementation of both [sshfs](http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/sshfs/ci/master/tree/sshfs.c#l3006) and [ntfs-3g](http://sourceforge.net/p/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g/ci/master/tree/src/ntfs-3g.c#l251) setting f_type in the statfs implementation of each of the these filesystems appears to be ignored.

I believe using this method would result in a value of 0x65735546 based on [the initialization of the value here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4f671fe2f9523a1ea206f63fe60a7c7b3a56d5c7/fs/fuse/inode.c).

A mechanism to get filesystem information in userspace is `/proc/mounts` or `/proc/<pid>/mountinfo` as documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt). This has the 9th field as filesystem type which has FUSE subtypes (if they were specified as a mount option and supported by the kernel) as type.subtype. E.g fuse.sshfs or fuse.ntfs-3g.

To access the same information in kernelspace , you can use [lookup_mnt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/namespace.c) with the path, to get a pointer to a vfsmount struct, from that you can access the superblock and then the subtype. Where `struct vfsmount *mnt` and the subtype is `mnt->mnt_sb->s_subtype`.